# Align elements in a line but in different positons

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am learning HTML and I am trying to align different icons in a line but in a different positions. The first element should be aligned to the left and the others aligned to the right.

```
E1|              |E2|E3|E4
```

I am not sure how to implement that. Should I use a `table`? Or a `div` with `<li>` elements?

I tried to use a table with a blank column but it's not working

```css
td {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="60%"> test </td>
    <td> blank </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

[Flex ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.box div {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.e1{
  flex: .1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="e1">E1</div>
  <div>E2</div>
  <div>E3</div>
  <div>E4</div>
</div>
```

or using table

```css
td {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td width="60%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>E3</td>
    <td>E4</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me what does the flex: .1 0 0; means?

Comment: I linked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax)

Answer (score 0):

A common method for this is to use `display: flex` for the container and apply `margin-left: auto` to the first of the child elements that should be moved to the right. That way that left margin will grow as wide as possible within the given container and with the given settings:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
</div>
```